# Catching paths of inaccessible folders from Get-Childitem

Tags: powershell, error-handling, get-childitem

I am working on small script to capture file hashes on a running system. I only have Powershell available.

This is the active part of the code:

```
get-childitem -path $path -filter $filename -Recurse -Force | Select FullName | foreach-object { get-filehash $_.fullname | select * }
```

this is the command I am testing with:

```
./Get-FileHashesRecursive.ps1 -path c:\ -filename *.txt
```

When running the script I get a series of errors because certain folders are inaccessible. I'd like to record the paths of those folders so the user has a record on completion of what failed.

the error looks like this in a console window:

```
get-childitem : Access to the path 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-4167544967-4010527683-3770225279-9182' is denied.
At E:\git\Get-RemoteFileHashesRecursive\Get-FileHashesRecursive.ps1:14 char:9
+         get-childitem -path $path -filter $filename -Recurse -Force | ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\$Recycle.Bin...3770225279-9182:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Is there a way I can grab the path or the entire first line of the error WITHOUT stopping the rest of the script from running?

Comment: Why not add `-ErrorVariable FailedItems -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to your `Get-ChildItem` parameters Then once you've completed your command, add another, something like this, `$FailedItems | Foreach-Object {$_.CategoryInfo.TargetName} | Out-File "C:\Users\sailingbikeruk\Desktop\noaccess.log"`. Hopefully you should then get a file listing all of the directories which were giving the UnauthorizedAccessException errors

Comment: It may be useful to also include the `-File` parameter with your `Get-ChildItem` command too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here's my earlier comments as an answer:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filename -File -Recurse -Force -ErrorVariable FailedItems -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object { Get-FileHash -Path $_.FullName | Select-Object * }
$FailedItems | Foreach-Object {$_.CategoryInfo.TargetName} | Out-File "C:\Users\sailingbikeruk\Desktop\noaccess.log"
```

- I have added the `-File` parameter to `Get-ChildItem`, because you are specifically dealing with only files.
- I also added the `-ErrorVariable` and `-ErrorAction` parameters to the `Get-ChildItem` command. `-ErrorVariable FailedItems` defines a custom name for a variable which stores errors from the command during processing. `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, tells the script to continue without notifying you of the errors.
- Once your command has finished processing, you can parse the content of the `$FailedItems` variable. In the example above, I've output the `TargetName` to a file so that you can read it at your leisure, *(please remember to adjust its file path and name as needed, should you also wish to output it to a file).*

Comment: `ErrorRecord` has a member [`TargetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord.targetobject?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_ErrorRecord_TargetObject) which stores the path too. Is there a reason to prefer `CategoryInfo.TargetName`?

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll test this over the weekend and mark it as answered once tested. I wasn't aware of the -ErrorVariable parameter, that could prove very useful in the future.

Comment: @zett42 How would you access TargetObject, can you expand your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Compo apologies for the delay in any response. Ive tried your solution and it works if the error is "access denied" but it doesn't appear to create an entry in ErrorVariable if the error is `The file <filename> cannot be read: The process cannot access the file <filename> because it is being used by another process`. I don't have confidence that it is reporting all access Errors.

Comment: That is another question completely, and after ten days, with no acceptance of the answer, which you've stated works, and which fully dealt with the question asked, I am not going to post another solution for you for that new question within this one. When I answer a question, I do not sign up to be a forever support specialist for your further questions. Please create a new question, if you have one, and please if you do, remember that we assist you with a fix for a specific reproducible issue for your provided code, we do not write code for you to add new functionality you've not included.

Comment: @sailingbikeruk `$_.TargetObject`