# Catching errors and handling blocked files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, error-handling

The history of this question lies in an earlier question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505799/catching-paths-of-inaccessible-folders-from-get-childitem)

I am running this command to get the file hashes of all files in a given location,  but I need to capture any that are missed or inaccessible.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filename -File -Recurse -Force -ErrorVariable FailedItems -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object { Get-FileHash -Path $_.FullName | Select-Object * }
$FailedItems | Foreach-Object {$_.CategoryInfo.TargetName} | Out-File "C:\Users\sailingbikeruk\Desktop\noaccess.log"
```

In the earlier question I thought that I just needed to catch folders, and the answer given and accepted did capture any folder access denied messages but the command doesn't capture individual files that are inaccessible. The suggested answer (using -errorvariable) doesn't appear to record the path of these.

I am not clear as to why the -ErrorVariable is catching the paths from this error:

```
get-childitem : Access to the path 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-4167544967-4010527683-3770225279-9182' is denied.
At E:\git\Get-RemoteFileHashesRecursive\Get-FileHashesRecursive.ps1:14 char:9
+         get-childitem -path $path -filter $filename -Recurse -Force | ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\$Recycle.Bin...3770225279-9182:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

but not this one

```
Get-FileHash : The file 'E:\devices.csv' cannot be read: The process cannot access the file
'E:\devices.csv' because it is being used by another process.
At E:\Scripts\Ian\git\Get-RemoteFileHashesRecursive\Get-FileHashesRecursive.ps1:25 char:132
+ ... FailedItems | ForEach-Object { Get-FileHash -Path $_.FullName | Selec ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (E:\devices.csv:PSObject) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileReadError,Get-FileHash
```

In this example I am writing `$_.CategoryInfo.TargetName` to the error log, but I have also tried writing `$_.TargetObject` and get the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common parameters `-ErrorVariable` and `-ErrorAction` apply to a single command only. So you have to add them to `Get-FileHash` too:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filename -File -Recurse -Force -ErrorVariable FailedItems -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        Get-FileHash -Path $_.FullName -ErrorVariable +FailedItems -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object * 
    }

$FailedItems | Foreach-Object {$_.CategoryInfo.TargetName} | Out-File "C:\Users\sailingbikeruk\Desktop\noaccess.log"
```

Note that I have inserted `+` in front of the error variable name for `Get-FileHash` to prevent it from clearing any errors produced by `Get-ChildItem`. See [about_CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.1#long-description).

**Unrelated improvements**:

You can remove `ForEach-Object` and just pipe `Get-ChildItem` directly into `Get-FileHash`. Also `Select-Object *` is superfluous.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filename -File -Recurse -Force -ErrorVariable FailedItems -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Get-FileHash -ErrorVariable +FailedItems -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Thank you that has worked just as I needed it to. Answer marked accordingly. Nice tip re the `+` sign as well thanks